# Javascript slider problem

Tags: javascript, css, nan, parseint

Hi I am currently working on a script given to me by my boss and it is not working in all browsers except IE.

Now he is using the CSS property left to animate it so he has a variable which gets the current value of left. For example lets say left is equal to `-100px`.

Now once it has this value it adds `10px` onto the value to make it move in from the left.

Now my issue lies with `parseInt()` and the `"px"` prefix at the end of the number. it keeps returning `NaN` instead of the value of left.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE:**
Ok I have rewritten the code and [it can be viewed here](http://pastebin.com/aZLJgiAk), by re-written I mean I have took my bosses code and changed variable names and commented it to make it easier to understand and see what it trying to be accomplished with the javascript.

Now the slider is meant to make he selected DIV slide in from the left and into place (the DIV is offet by -760px) in IE this works fine, but not in any other browser. I have however come up with a fix in a way for the other browsers. by removing the `px` in the stylesheet from the end of -760 it causes the DIV to appear but it does not slide in how it should.

To make it easier im going to supply the sliders html and CSS for them here to hpefully help a little.

[The HTML](http://pastebin.com/kGNW25Hk)

[The CSS](http://pastebin.com/fp6crjxj)

Comment: What exactly is the code causing `NaN`?

Comment: `w=parseInt(document.getElementById(slideDiv).style.left);
 
 if(w<0)
 {
  w=w+10;
  document.getElementById(slideDiv).style.left =w 
 }`

Comment: @robf92: Are you sure `.style.left` is set explicitly? You might also want to use `.offsetLeft`.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by explicitly. But yes it is set to a default value in css

`left: -760px;`

Comment: Is adding jquery to the page an option?  It's hard to imagine dealing directly with CSS positioning changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try catch

```
try{
  w=parseInt(document.getElementById("slideDiv").style.left+"make me string");
}catch(e){
  w=0;
  alert(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: The problem I am having is that it is not getting the elements current position becasue it is returning -760px which obvoisuly is not an integer becasue of the "px"

Comment: Sorry I misread at first, but parseInt's job is to look for a number inside of a string, disregarding letter characters.

Comment: tried this and the alert returns:

TypeError: document.getElementById("slideDiv") is null

@Tank ah ok, this is my first exerience with Javascript, my current position is an apprentice at a software development company so yea its all rather confusing for me atm :D

Comment: That error is saying that "slideDiv" is not there. This could be due to "slideDiv" having not yet loaded. Check out jQuery and $(document).ready(function(){...}); which waits for the html to be loaded before running code.

Comment: The quick and dirty way to make sure the code is loaded is to put your javascript code all the way at the bottom of the page, just before </body>

Comment: @Tank oh ok, he does not want jQuery using as far as I know, and as for loading the javascript at the bottom of the page would i just move my `<script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>` to the bottom?

Comment: @Tank I have just noticed that in the above code you have used quotes around slidediv, wouldnt this mean that it would then check the document for a division with the id of slideDiv as opposed to checking the slideDiv variable which is being used to store the current Division? Thanks.

Comment: @robf92 yes, that would check for an element named "slideDiv"... I assumed that is what you had named the div since I saw no variable declaration for slideDiv. If the slideDiv is the div obj, then you would do slideDiv.style.left=

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

Comment: I just tried alerting parseFloat("-170px"); in my console and it worked fine. What is the actual value of "document.getElementById(slideDiv).style.left" because I don't think that's correct

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
// should return e.g. "10px":
var valueAsString = document.getElementById('slideDiv').style.left;

// remove "px" at the end, so w will only contain "10":
numericPartOfValue = value.substring(0, value.length - 2);
var w = parseInt(numericPartOfValue);

if(w < 0) { 
   w = w+10; 
   // Note: Updated after the comment below:
   document.getElementById(slideDiv).style.left =w + "px";
}
```

Comment: hmm thank you but using this breaks it in IE aswell

Why does Javascript have to be so troublesome? D:

Im just going to post the whole javascript file. As I say it has been written by my boss and not me. my Javascript knowledge is rather basic at the moment

[link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NEmgVFQx)

One thing I have found out is that removing the "px" from the CSS file makes it work kind of (the sliders change but without the "slide in" animation)

I would also like to thank everyone for their help so far, you are all great people and I am very appreciative. Thank you all :)

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, then the change I just made should fix it (see the code comment): Simply add "px" to the end again, after you're done handling the numeric value.

Comment: Nope still not working, well I say not working, IE now animates to about 1/7th of the way across and then it just stops, and all the other browsers still do not work, Thanks.

Comment: It might be easier to help you out if we could see how this was supposed to work. Maybe you could provide some of the HTML as well?

Comment: Sorry I left work and completely forgot about this. So what HTML would you need? just the divs that are being "slid"?

also as I am thinking about it im thinking that it has to be something with slideDiv as someone else has said parseInto should remove the "px" and upon testing it that is correct. I was also thinking that it had something to do with using `zIndex` instead of `z-index` as i read somewhere that it can cause issues with other browsers but upon changing that it breaks in both firefox and IE so my suspision lies with slideDiv.

Comment: **CONTINUED** so I decided to just set slideDiv manually but it is still returning NaN. so at this point I am somewhat confused about why this is not working...

Anyone who can help please do so, I shall be forever in your debt if you can fix this problem for me. Thank you all again.